# Op-amps that get really close to the supply voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier

I've heard that I can get an Op-amp that will be able to get it's output to within a few millivolts of the supply voltage.

Do these exist? If so then where or how do I find them.

If you want specifics, it needs to be able to work at 3.6 volts, have two op-amps and be available in a SOIC 8.

Thanks.

Comment: Look for opamps that have "rail-to-rail" outputs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is called a rail-to-rail op-amp. [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/linear-amplifiers-instrumentation-op-amps-buffer-amps/2556125?k=op%20amp) lets you narrow by that as a parameter, under "Output Type". Some of the more common ones in the package you want include:
[LMC662](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LMC662AIMX/NOPB/LMC662AIMX/NOPBCT-ND/2139055)
[TS912](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TS912IDT/497-6618-1-ND/1865448)
[LMV358](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LMV358IDT/497-4945-1-ND/1003416)
[MCP6002](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MCP6002-I/SN/MCP6002-I/SN-ND/500876)

I've personally made good use of MCP6002 in a DIP8 package.

Comment: Sorry for lateness, forgot I'd posted this. Thanks very much, great help. I'll find the one I want.

Answer (score 3):

Most opamps with CMOS outputs will do this.  The magic search term is "rail to rail outputs".

Note however that there is no such things as a truly rail to rail output opamp when you draw any current from the output.  All output drivers will have some resistance.  The term rail-to-rail is therefore a bit misleading.  It basically means those opamps that drive to either rail with only a FET in on state between the output and the rail, as apposed to those that have one or more unavoidable junction drops or other overhead between the rails and the output.

Check out the MCPxxx line from Microchip.  These are very nice opamps with a variety of tradeoffs as long as you don't need more than 5.5 V supply capability.  If you want opamps that run from the same supply as a microcontroller, this is usually the first place to look.  These are all CMOS opamps with "rail to rail" output, among many other nice features.